# Javascript: select 2 options to show measurement type and time interval at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Selecting `viewOptions` changes between weather measurement function. And `interval4` shows data based on selected time intervals. My goal is to first be able to change between the measurement types and then select time intervals within the measurement type (eg: temperature ->24hrs).
Right now,  the measurement types change but the time interval data does not reflect in my chart and table(functions I have opted out).
How do I get the result where both the `select options` work and accept the parameters and reflect the change in data?

```js
function select_measurement(measurement_type=" ",interval=" "){
  switch(measurement_type){
    case "1":getTemperature(interval);break;
    case "2":getWind_speed(interval);break;
    case "3":getWind_direction(interval);break;
    case "4":getLight(interval);break;
    case "5":getRain(interval);break;
   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewOptions">
  <label for="viewOptions">Choose Measurement type</label>
  <select onchange ="select_measurement (this.value, ' ')">
  <option value="1">Temperature</option>
  <option value="2">Wind Speed</option>
  <option value="3">Wind Direction</option>
  <option value="4">Light</option>
  <option value="5">rain</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="interval4">
  <label for="interval4">Choose time</label>
  <select onchange ="select_measurement(' ',this.value)">

  <option value=" ">Now</option>
  <option value="23">24hrs</option>
  <option value="47">48hrs</option>
  <option value="71">72hrs</option>
  <option value="167">Week</option>
  <option value="729">Month</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to get the value of the other select element when one of them changes. So I would insert the value of the other select element into the `onchange` attribute.

```js
function select_measurement(measurement_type = " ", interval = " ") {
  switch (measurement_type) {
    case "1":
      getTemperature(interval);
      break;
    case "2":
      getWind_speed(interval);
      break;
    case "3":
      getWind_direction(interval);
      break;
    case "4":
      getLight(interval);
      break;
    case "5":
      getRain(interval);
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewOptions">
  <label for="viewOptions">Choose Measurement type</label>
  <select id="viewOptions-select" onchange="select_measurement(this.value, document.getElementById('interval4-select').value)">
    <option value="1" selected>Temperature</option>
    <option value="2">Wind Speed</option>
    <option value="3">Wind Direction</option>
    <option value="4">Light</option>
    <option value="5">Rain</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="interval4">
  <label for="interval4">Choose time</label>
  <select id="interval4-select" onchange="select_measurement(document.getElementById('viewOptions-select').value ,this.value)">
    <option value=" " selected>Now</option>
    <option value="23">24hrs</option>
    <option value="47">48hrs</option>
    <option value="71">72hrs</option>
    <option value="167">Week</option>
    <option value="729">Month</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I might have been vague with my explanation. to make it clearer,  I have a graph and a table which GETs data from a JSON api and displays them in the graph.  `select_measurement` function is meant to display the various api chocies such as temperature, wind speed data according to the users choice. `interval4` id is another drop down menu which allows users to select the time frame of the data they want to see, which is 24hrs, 48hrs etc....
where i am having problem is, i am able to switch between measurement types but i cannot change the time frame of the selected measurement type.